# How to use "run as" with elasticsearch js client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch has a nifty "run as user" feature that I would like to use for testing:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/run-as-privilege.html

I'm using the javascript library (in typescript) to interact with my es clusters:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html

I want to send specific requests (eg. search or post a document) with my user credentials, but run the request as another user. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems like the JS client allow you to pass custom headers in the basic client configuration: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/basic-config.html You should be able to add the `es-security-runas-user: ${target_user}` there

Comment: Indeed, that's the only solution I've got so far. I was hoping for something cleaner, though :)